# Tab Host Issue in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent, android-widget

I want to display a tab at bottom of screen , so i use

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@android:id/tabcontent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

but also want to display a button below tab widget . At bottom of screen , we have a button and a tab widget which is above button but should be at bottom of screen .

There is any way for doing it.

Please suggest me usable link or sample code.

Comment: did you google? there are many answer already on StackOverflow for the same question and also on the web.

Comment: http://envyandroid.com/archives/326/align-tabhost-at-bottom

Comment: my problem is not to display tab at bottom , but display a button below tab host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use linear-layout and put the tabhost and button in it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but take one Linear or Relative Layout.
Put TabHost first and then put a button in that new Layout below TabHost.

I have not used it but I think it will work